# Paraview crashed: "../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory"

Tags: paraview

I installed Paraview and It seems there was no error when I compiled it. There is no problem when I run `paraview --help` or `paraview --version`. But it crashed (aborted (core dumped) when I invoked paraview. I'm wondering if someone has similar experience and can help me out of this issue.

I ran gdb and got the following information:

```
(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1806/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.5.2/bin/paraview 

process 16370 is executing new program: /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1806/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.5.2/lib/paraview

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

[New Thread 0x7fffd1baf700 (LWP 16382)]

[New Thread 0x7fffc73c1700 (LWP 16383)]

[New Thread 0x7fffc6bc0700 (LWP 16384)]

[New Thread 0x7fffb5a09700 (LWP 16393)]

[New Thread 0x7fffaa1cc700 (LWP 16394)]

[New Thread 0x7fffa3fff700 (LWP 16395)]

[New Thread 0x7fffa99cb700 (LWP 16396)]

[New Thread 0x7fffa91ca700 (LWP 16397)]


Thread 1 "paraview" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51

51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

---

download paraview from paraview website, ran and got the same crash result. gdb information are:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/ParaView-5.6.0-RC2-Qt5-MPI-Linux-64bit/bin/paraview 
process 10177 is executing new program: /home/ubuntu/ParaView-5.6.0-RC2-Qt5-MPI-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffcac8c700 (LWP 10205)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbd98e700 (LWP 10214)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbd18d700 (LWP 10215)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbc98c700 (LWP 10216)]
[New Thread 0x7fffaffff700 (LWP 10217)]

Thread 1 "paraview" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please provide the following information:
OS, GPU, ParaView version.

Are you using OpenFOAM' s paraview ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using paraview that comes with OpenFOAM 1806. OS: ubunut 18.04 LTS, paraView version 5.5.2.  I'm not familiar iwth GPU. Using command lshw -C display, I got "description: VGA compatible controller, product: GD 5446, vendor: Cirrus Logic". Thanks for responding

Comment: please try to use the release version of ParaView https://www.paraview.org/download/

Comment: Thanks and I will download it.

Comment: Very correct of the OP's to try to launch `paraview --help` or  `paraview --version`. This check helps isolate if there's something wrong with the installation or, for example, with the driver for the graphics card.